# Hibernate request : how to format dates in my result

Tags: hibernate, date, format, transform, criteria

I'm try to create an hibernate criteria to extract the dates in format 'yyyy/MM/dd' (they are in 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss' format in database).

How can I transform the result in my projection ?

For now, my criteria looks like :

final DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass( Measure.class )
    .add( Restrictions.eq( "plateform.plateformId", plateformId ) );

criteria.setProjection( Projections.property( "measureDate" ) );
  final List dates = criteria.getExecutableCriteria( _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() ).list();

I don't want all the dates where there is measures, I want only the days there is measures.

Any idea ? Haven't find anything until now (ResultTransformer ???).
Thanks a lot for your help,
vanessa

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you get those dates as it is and then convert them to your requirement using simpledateformatter APIs..

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I have a lot of measure's dates (> 15 000, one measure every 15 seconds by example), and I don't want to extract all this dates (too long). I just want the days (much less results).

Comment: ok, can you explain more on your requirement? what does this mean? -> `I don't want all the dates where there is measures, I want only the days there is measures`.